# Performance test went wrong and the dd command created 13TB of data on /dev/mapper/device. Why system didn't crash? HDD-250GB

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, dd, embedded

So I wanted to do some performance test with encrypted and normal data storage on my embedded device.

**That is not what I was expected to see at all!**

Can you please explain it to me what just happend. Why `dd` comand output was 1843200+0 records but `df -h` show file system disk space usage as **13TB**?

Maybe I explain what I have done. This is my workflow:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=enc_per_test.img bs=512 count=2097152

dd if=/dev/urandom of=normal_per_test.img bs=512 count=2097152
```

And receive 2 images 1GB each - as I predicted.

```
losetup /dev/loop1 enc_per_test.img 

losetup /dev/loop2 normal_per_test.img
```

After that I perform:

```
dmsetup -v create enc_per_test --table "0 $(blockdev --getsz /dev/loop1) crypt <crypt_setup> 0 /dev/loop1 0 1 sector_size:512"

mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/enc_per_test

mkdir /mnt/enc_per_test

mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/enc_per_test /mnt/enc_per_test/
```

As I expected `df-h` showed mounted enc_per_test:

```
 Filesystem ############## Size ### Used ## Avail ## Use% ### Mounted on #####           

 /dev/mapper/enc_per_test ## 976M ## 2.6M ## 907M ## 1% #### /mnt/enc_per_test
```

I clear cache:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

**And finally perform dd comand to fill up the enc_per_test:**

```
time dd if=/tmp/random of=/dev/mapper/enc_per_test conv=fsync

1843200+0 records in
1843200+0 records out
943718400 bytes (944 MB, 900 MiB) copied, 152.098 s, 6.2 MB/s
```

So I was like, ok that's fine. This is what I wanted. Let's see how it's look like in df -h:

```
 Filesystem ############## Size ### Used ## Avail ## Use% ### Mounted on #####           

 /dev/mapper/enc_per_test ## 13T ## 13T ## 0 ## 100% #### /mnt/enc_per_test
```

What happned here? Why `df -h`show **13TB** of data storage. It is even not possible because my device has ~250GB of hard drive.

Thank you for any answer and hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mounted a filesystem existing in `/dev/mapper/enc_per_test` (the device) to `/mnt/enc_per_test/` (the mountpoint).

Then with `dd` you chose to write to the *device*, not to a regular file inside the filesystem (i.e. under the mountpoint, e.g. `of=/mnt/enc_per_test/blob`). **Your `dd` overwrote the majority of the filesystem with the content of `/tmp/random` while the filesystem was mounted.**

`df` queries mounted filesystems. For a given filesystem the fields `Size`, `Used` and such are what the filesystem knows and reports about itself. Probably some data, metadata and information about the filesystem in question was still available as old values in the cache, so it seemed sane enough; but apparently something new had to be read from the device. Some part(s) of the garbage you had written was read, [hence the surprising values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

The statement in the title is wrong. It's not true that "`dd` command created 13TB of data". `13T` appeared only because `df` got some random values from what *used to be* a filesystem.

Comment: Is there any chance to remove this trash I accidentally put to my file system?
I tried with: dmsetup remove enc_per_test and unmount /mnt/enc_per_test
but now I see the problem is not so easy to resolved.
How can I check the actual disk usage if df -h shows everything is ok?

Comment: @What_is_my_name You put trash to the device, not to the filesystem. The filesystem is no more. With `mkfs.ext4` you can create a new filesystem inside the device. `umount` the "ghost" of the old one first (but I'm not sure if this will succeed). In case of any doubt just reboot. After the reboot the only remnants will be these `enc_per_test.img` and `normal_per_test.img` regular files.